# Can someone else patent an invention that I have introduced in my open source project?

Tags: license-recommendation, copyright, law, patents, license

Is open source protected in any way if I haven't filed for a patent myself? Maybe a specific license?
Any examples of open source projects that introduced 'inventions' that could be patented (but they were not) would be really appreciated.

*And please take into consideration: design & utility patents.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, no: once you've published your idea (whether as open source or not), it becomes part of the "prior art" and is no longer eligible to be patented. Patents are for *innovation*, and almost by definition something can't be innovative if it's just taking someone else's idea.